# How to prove that "Type <> Set" (i.e. Type is not equal to Set) in Coq?

Tags: coq, dependent-type, theorem-proving, type-theory

Is there an equality or inequality relation between `Type` and `Set` in Coq ?

I am learning about Coq's type system and understand that the type of `Set` is `Type@{Set+1}`, and that the type of `Type@{k}` is `Type@{k+1}`. I tried to prove that `Type = Set`, and then tried to prove  `Type <> Set`, but I failed in both cases.

I started with

```
Lemma set_is_type :  Type = Set.
Proof.
reflexivity.
```

which gives an error message saying that *Unable to unify "Set" with "Type@{Top.74}"*.

Then I tried

```
Lemma set_is_not_type : Type <> Set.
Proof.
intros contra.
```

At this point I do not know how to proceed. The tactic `discriminate` did not work, neither `inversion contra`.

Which one of the above two lemmas can be proved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This actually isn't an entirely trivial theorem. To show that `Type = Set` results in a paradox (and hence that having separate levels of `Type` is necessary), you'll need to use a standard result akin to Russell's paradox from set theory. Specifically, you'll need [Hurken's paradox](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.Hurkens.html), which essentially says that smaller `Type`s can't be on equal footing to larger `Type`s (remember that `Type` is polymorphic in Coq, and in particular, `Set` is the lowest level (or second lowest if you include `Prop`)).

The particular theorem we want can be found in the standard library.

```
Require Logic.Hurkens.
Import Logic.Hurkens.TypeNeqSmallType.

Check paradox.
```

`paradox` has the type signature `forall A : Type, Type = A -> False`. This is pretty much what we want to prove, since `Set: Type` (at least if `Type` is large enough).

```
Lemma set_is_not_type: Type <> Set.
Proof.
  intro F.
  exact (paradox _ F).
Defined.
```

Coq automatically sets restrictions on the `Type` in this lemma to ensure that `Set: Type`.

---

On the other hand, `Set` is equal to *some* level of `Type`, so we should be able to prove that `Type = Set` with some different constraints on this `Type`. The easiest way I found to do this was to prove that `Type = Type`, but then instantiate this theorem with `Set`. For whatever reason, as you found, reflexivity can't enforce universe constraints by itself. To do this, we need to make both the lemmas universe polymorphic so that they can be instantiated with a particular universe level.

```
Polymorphic Lemma type_is_type: Type = Type.
Proof.
  reflexivity.
Defined.

Polymorphic Lemma type_is_set: Type = Set.
Proof.
  apply type_is_type.
Defined.
```

The easier way to make everything universe polymorphic is to put `Set Universe Polymorphism.` before everything.